# Uploading File to a Shared Folder in a File Server in PHP using REST API

Tags: php, curl, file-upload

Currently I am trying to upload file from my PHP form to a file server (shared folder) via API. Files which are less than 65KB uploads fine, but when I try to upload 80KB or higher, it doesnt go into the shared folder. I have already configured my php.ini to accept 20MB (`post_max_size` & `upload_max_filesize`). I worried there are server configuration blocking my file upload, but I dont know where to check. I'm doing this project on my Window server 2019, appreciate it if anyone can help.

Below is my code to upload using API:

```
if (isset($_POST['on'])) {
    $tempfile = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $uploadUrl = 'http://APIURL/common/upload'; // Update this to the correct upload URL

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array(
        $curl,
        array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $uploadUrl,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file_id' => 'image', 'file' => new CURLFile($tempfile, 'image/jpeg', $fileName)),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
            ),
        )
    );

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($response === false) {
        // An error occurred
        $error = curl_error($curl);
        $errno = curl_errno($curl);
        echo "cURL error ($errno): $error";
    } else {
        // Upload was successful
        echo "File uploaded successfully!";
    }

    curl_close($curl);    
}
```

Comment: Hello there!
What is the web server that serves your application? is it Nginx, Apache, or something else? Are you by any chance using PHP-FPM?
If you're using PHP-FPM, you need to restart the PHP-FPM service for your changes to take effect, and make sure to restart your web server daemon

Comment: Hi, im using PHP and hosted in IIS

Comment: Alright, can you try restarting your IIS instance and see if the problem is resolved?
Sometimes, you have to restart your web server software for the changes in `php.ini` to take effects

Comment: Yes, i have restarted my IIS, and double check in my phpinfo() as well. It shows the changes i made but still the files which are 80KB or more cannot be uploaded.

Comment: There's two parts to this here - the files getting uploaded to your server, and then from your server, via the API, to the shared folder. So the first thing to do here, is to figure out _which_ of those parts fails. Make a var_dump of $_FILES, and check for errors.

Comment: In this case, it's very likely to be an IIS configuration issue, so you need to check and see what configuration options you have. Unfortunately, I don't have enough experience on this topic since I've never used IIS before, but I found the following link which might help you: https://www.inflectra.com/Support/KnowledgeBase/KB306.aspx

Comment: "*it doesnt go into the shared folder*" - what does happen?  Do you see any errors?  What are you getting back as `$response`?  Does the API really return `false` when an upload fails or is rejected?  Check the API docs, I'd expect some kind of error to let you know what the problem is, maybe as JSON - try `echo`ing `$response` to see.  Are there any settings/limits on the API end you need to configure?

Comment: @CBroe Uploading to temp folder within my server is okay, from temp folder to file server using API is the part that fail. I have tested the API using POSTMAN for file less than 60KB, and it was successful, but more than that (80KB) it fails. I have tried printing error logs but i have found none.

Comment: So the problem appears to be on the API side then. What result are you actually getting? Do you see your "cURL error (...): ..." output? If not, maybe you should check what the non-false response actually contains then.

Comment: @Don'tPanic i only got 'cURL error (56): Recv failure: Connection was reset' error. But i dont know any other file upload setting to check except for php.ini. Do you have any other suggestion where to check?